# How to fix Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms with Jenkins ALM plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hp-uft, alm

I am a new user to Jenkins and working to get the Jenkins to run the QC tests sets.  We are using ALM\QC v12.2 vUFT 12.54, and Jenkins with QC plugin 5.0.  When running the build from Jenkins, I get this console info below.  I cannot turn off FIPS via  the Control Panel but maybe able to make a registry change.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
[vmused] $ C:\temp\workspace\vmused\HpToolsLauncher.exe -paramfile props03022017152501685.txt
"Started..."
Timeout is set to: 180
Run mode is set to: RUN_LOCAL

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor()    
at  HpToolsLauncher.Launcher.Decrypt(String textToDecrypt, String key)   
at HpToolsLauncher.Launcher.CreateRunner(TestStorageType runType, avaProperties ciParams)
   at HpToolsLauncher.Launcher.Run()
   at HpToolsLauncher.Program.Main(String[] args)
Recording test results
None of the test reports contained any result
RunResultRecorder: didn't find any test results to record
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Back when I used to be in HP, I created this QCCR for FIPS, basically HP does not comply and it deferred the request for support.

RnD: QCCR1J74956 
KM: https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM01198673

I also found newer request but its a ticket, thus no one outside HP vpn can see it.

[FIPS ticket snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNMB.png)

I would recommend that if its not required by your company, to disable it . But if its something required and urgent, to open an ER.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Jenkins.  HP didn't provide any help.  I also asked my organization if we could disable FIPS somehow for the test machines.  Works great with FIPS off.